# How can we name different deployment environments in Russian?

Tags: терминология

During a software development process, software is usually deployed on different environments, which also have different names and roles, depending on the team and development process:

- Development environment
- Testing environment
- QA environment
- Staging environment
- Pre-production environment
- Production environment

There are probably even more names out there. But I never found a translation of them.
How would you call those environments or systems in Russian?

Comment: Thanks @shabunc and vik-williams for your answer. That was very helpful! As I am not a native speaker I cannot really judge, which answer is correct. Both also have the same amount of votes.
However the only real difference appears to be at Development: 

Those are "девелоперское окружение" / "девелоперский энвайронмент" vs. "среда разработки"

I really cannot tell, whom to assign the "correct solution". Any ideas?

Comment: IMHO "среда разработки" usually means IDE. "Девелоперское окружение" sounds awkward (even though it is correct). In my experience, most Russians use "дев", "стейджинг" и "прод" when talking about various environments (e. g. "Мы залили сборку Х на дев", "Фича У доступна на стейджинге").

Comment: Feel free to accept Vik`s answer! Just like you I can clearly see they are equivalent and encouraging new users is a good thing to do! ("окружение" and "среда" are interchangeable in this particular context btw though I agree with Dmitrii that first thing I would have though about is IDE)

Comment: https://ru.hexlet.io/blog/posts/environment

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Development environment - среда разработки

Testing environment - среда для тестирования (среда тестирования)

QA environment - среда контроля качества

Staging environment - стейджинг

Pre-Production environment - пре-продакшен (пре-прод, пре-прода)

Production environment - продакшен (прод, прода)

А вообще, эти выражения можно говорить на английском. Русские программисты (и другие айтишники) поймут вас.

Comment: I work in IT and I've never heard "cреда разработки" to be used in other meaning than "IDE". And for different deployments it's either "окружение", "энвайромент" or "энв".

Comment: @Alissa я защищу своего товарища по ответам - это реже встречается и конкретно с разработкой да, получилось неудачно, всё-таки даже если говорят среда то тогда дев, чтобы не путать с IDE - но в остальном так говорят - про тестовую среду например точно говорят (но реже, чем про окружение)

Comment: @shabunc может быть где-то и встречается "дев среда", не буду спорить. Хотя я честно ни разу не слышала чтобы так говорили (да и других "сред" не припомню), может это региональные особенности, я не знаю. Мое основное возражение касалось "среды разработки" и тут как раз мы с вами вроде согласны :).

Answer (score 5):

Those are "девелоперское окружение" (or even "девелоперский энвайормент" - pronounced usually closer to "энвайромент" however), or just simple "дев", "тестинг" or (very rarely and in official documentation) "тестовое окружение", "стейджинг", "препродакшн" or "препрод" and, finally, "продакшен", or just "прод".

Whether we like it or not, huge portion of dev-related terminology is used as is in English - and therefore became a part of Russian vocabulary just like the words "танк", "гаубица" or "телеграф" did it before. However every time one need to check. For instance, branches in version control are called interchangeably "бранч" and "ветка", for DB connections one can hear both "подключение" and "коннекшен". Or, for example, the most widely adopted pronunciation for ssh is "эс-эс-аш", not "эс-эс-эйч".

Answer (score 1):

As you cun see from other answer Russain language is under heavy siege from english terms. So you can just use english names and be understood.

As for "pure russian terms" (wich are not recognised by everybody - it sort of "cold language civil war" and are not so pure) I can suggest following translations:

- Development environment - среда разработки
- Testing environment - тестовое окружение, среда тестирования
- QA environment - контрольное окружение (it's more official term - rarely used in everyday speech )
- Staging environment - макетное окружение (almost never used - only in documents prepared according to ГОСТ standarts), макет
- Pre-production environment - опытное окружение, опытное производство (also rarely used - I've used it only in documents for industrial software)
- Production environment - рабочее окружение